# how to make a relationship table between 3 table (2 to 1) in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

lets say we have 3 table in our database

**tables:**

```
table books:
book_id
book_title
...


table magazines:
magazine_id
magazine_title
...


and genres:
genre_id:
genre_name
```

and now we say want to know what book has what genre and what magazine has what genre, this is the way i know for two table

**relation tables:**

```
table book_genres:
genre_id
book_id


table magazine_genre:
genre_id
magazine_id
```

in this way we have to create several separate table for joining the books, magazine and maybe more tables. and i been told that always have 2 id column in join tables.

but i'm wondering about if i could do something like this

**the table that not working!**

```
table title_genres:
genre_id
book_id
magazine_id
...
```

this is more simple but i get an error when i insert a book genres that says `magazine_id` can't be empty `NULL` because its primary key.
its gonna be save me for creating a lot of tables. like if i decide to have a category table then i have to join books and magazine separately.
and my question: **is the 2 column thing is a good practice or there is a better way for this?**

Comment: add a id field and use this as primary

Comment: @nbk i asked some people and they said its not a good idea to have that in a join table is that right?

Comment: Your description cannot explain why books and magazines are treated as two separate entities. They look like different instances of one entity which were errorneously divided. So not two tables `books` and `magazines` but one table `publication`, maybe with the column `type` which may have a value `book` and `magazine`.

Comment: if you need to refer to a row, with multiple columns, than a auto_increment is the right choice

Comment: Research "Ternary Relationship".

Comment: @Akina that's understandable and make sense but how you divide those 2 table with their columns in that `publication` table. maybe we have more tables like books and magazines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use bridge tables to represent m:n relationships. If a book can have many genres and a magazine can have many genres, then you need bridge tables like the `book_genres` table you are showing.

And if books are very different from magazines in your database, then yes, have separate tables for books and magazines.

This leads to two bridge tables, just as you describe and I see nothing wrong with this.

Your idea to have one bridge table is generally possible, but doesn't solve any problem.

But well, let's see how we would construct such a multi bridge table. First of all you'll want a check constraint ensuring that always exactly one of the columns `book_id` and `magazine_id` is filled. Then you want a unique constraint on `COALESCE(book_id, magazine_id), genre_id`. This would usually be done with a function index, which MySQL doesn't support as far as I know. I suppose though, that you could create a generated column which you can index in MySQL.

And then you want to read the relations as quick as possible. With a bridge table like `book_genres` you have one row per book and genre and an index to get the relation as quick as possible. With a multi bridge table like `title_genres` you don't. You have one table containing relations you are interested in and others you are not interested in. You'd want a partial index like

```
create unique index idx on title_genres (book_id, genre_id) where book_id is not null;
```

but MySQL doesn't support partial indexes. You could

```
create unique index idx on title_genres (book_id, genre_id);
```

which leads to a larger index, but serves the purpose. You'd do the same with

```
create unique index idx2 on title_genres (magazine_id, genre_id);
```

And now, with all this work, what have you gained? Your database has become way more complicated than with the simple `book_genres` and `magazine_genres` tables. Keep it simple. Use these two tables instead of the multi bridge monster :-)

Comment: so it is the good practice to stick with separate tables. and it is simple and make sense.
but the one thing is terrifying me if i have more entity tables like this, like `books\magazines\newspapers...` and so on, and more tables like `genres\categories\languages\countries\` and its gonna be a lot of joining tables. and i afraid that's gonna effect on performance and whole database look a monster with a lot of tentacles.

Comment: You separate books from magazines, because you consider them very different. If you only stored title, ISBN, publishing house and an optional author, then you would have just one table for both as has been suggested. But you store author, summary, main characters for the book, but series, issue, and topics for the magazine (for instance), so you need two tables. And yes, with more m:n relations like multiple languages, etc. you need more bridge tables. However, as books are so very different from magazines, you will rarely have both in the same query. I wouldn't expect any performance issues.

Comment: At rare times you may want a single query instead of two separate ones (e.g. "show all books and magazines available in Dutch"), but that would not be a join, but a `UNION ALL`query. There is no performance penalty involved there. You probably won't ever join a book to a magazine, for what would be the purpose?

Comment: thank you so much Thorsten Kettner and that's all i need to know. well and i don't join a book to magazine and vice versa, but i do like a make category for click to see all books or magazines and etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely store the records this way if you have a category field that has information such as (books, magazines etc). So, in other words your table is vertically partitioned by category field but logically it’s a single table.

Only drawback I can see is if this table grows fast then query performance would be a problem because (a) the table will be huge so it will consume more memory even if you are only looking for specific categories and not all of them (b) you always have to use inline sub query since your category filter have to applied every time for every join and when you use inline queries for joins the database would not be able to make use of indexes will be affect the performance of the queries.

Note : You would not be able to store the records in any other way. For example even if a magazine and a book have same genre you have to have them in separate rows and not the same row because if you do that your model will get into other kind of troubles.

Comment: thank you Somy that is a good explaining. and i do worry about performance in this situation